# Parallel synchronous Service calls in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio, mule-esb

I have a request something like

```
{
  "wrapper": [
    {
      "key1": "A",
      "key2": "B"
    },
    {
      "key1": "C",
      "key2": "D"
    },
    {
      "key1": "E",
      "key2": "F"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to do Synchronous parallel call to a single API(endpoint) in mule, I cannot use `scatter gather` as 
1. There is **single Endpoint** 
2. the elements(list) inside wrapper can be of random size, as in above sample there are 3.

`VM` component is also ruled out, as there also calls would be sequential

**I'm able to process the data sequentially using `forEach` component, but can this be done in parallel ?**
If I could also collect data from each call that would be great.

Comment: Synchronous is sequential, because it will use the same thread and next thread will wait till the previous thread finishes. At best you can use **Async** block inside for-each for making all the thread parallel

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...So is this a limitation of mule that 'we cannot do parallel synchronous calls so same endpoint ?
As we can do same with different endpoints using Scatter Gather component.. but then again 'even for scatter gather we need to have fixed number of requests to be sent parallel (in my case that will be variable)

Comment: Could you please describe how  parallel synchronous calls would work better n any programming language? I'm trying to understand what is the request.

Comment: In java you can achieve this through threads, in AngularJS via fork operation.